# Installing troika-three-text from npm not working?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to add some texts to a scene in three-js and I've seen Troika seems to be perfect for it. The problem is that when I install troika, I can't find a way to call the module, and/or it has problems with references... I don't seem to find anything related anywhere, people ask questions like they simply install troika and voi-la, and for me it's been complicated

so I have three running perfectly,
then I install troika (npm install troika-three-text)

it generates some folders in the node_modules folder,
now the instalation tells you that you have to call it using

> import { Text } from 'troika-three-text',

when I do this, I get this message:

> 'Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier
> "troika-three-text". Relative references must start with either "/",
> "./", or "../".'

so then I try with:

> import { Text } from
> '../node_modules/troika-three-text/dist/troika-three-text.esm.js'

and now the problem is the following...

> 'Failed to resolve module specifier "troika-worker-utils". Relative
> references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".'

So I don't know what to do, either I have to *manually change every path inside the scripts of all the troika folders*, or what? it doesn't make any sense, please someone help me U_U thank you!!!

Comment: I assume the comma at the end of this line is just a typo? `import { Text } from 'troika-three-text',`

Comment: yes, the comma is a typo just here

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem as well while playing, with troika.

This may not be a perfect solution,but it's a good workaround because I use three.js in the browser, not in nodejs.
My main script is loaded in the index.html file using `type="module"` and also in the index.html file is an "import map" that uses defines the necessary names as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script type="importmap">
      {
      "imports" : {
          "three": "http://unpkg.com/three@latest/build/three.module.js",
          "troika-three-text": "http://unpkg.com/troika-three-text@latest/dist/troika-three-text.esm.js",
          "troika-three-utils": "http://unpkg.com/troika-three-utils@latest/dist/troika-three-utils.esm.js",
          "troika-worker-utils": "http://unpkg.com/troika-worker-utils@latest/dist/troika-worker-utils.esm.js",
           ...
      }
      }
    </script>
```

Note that I'm getting these files from the unpkg.com CDN. You may have to do something a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else needs it too, this is what ended up working for me - an extended importmap, including every dependency of troika text. SURELY there must be a better way, couldn't find it:

```
<script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "three": "https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js",
                "three/": "https://unpkg.com/three/",
                "troika-three-text": "https://unpkg.com/troika-three-text@latest/dist/troika-three-text.esm.js",
                "troika-three-utils": "https://unpkg.com/troika-three-utils@latest/dist/troika-three-utils.esm.js",
                "troika-worker-utils": "https://unpkg.com/troika-worker-utils@latest/dist/troika-worker-utils.esm.js",
                "webgl-sdf-generator": "https://unpkg.com/webgl-sdf-generator@latest/dist/webgl-sdf-generator.mjs",
                "bidi-js":             "https://unpkg.com/bidi-js@latest/dist/bidi.mjs"
            }
        }
    </script>
```